# MySQL WHERE by AS Statement

Tags: php, mysql

My Tables

```
Table1 :
___________________________________
| ID | UserID | Amount | Date     |
___________________________________
| 1  | 1      | 10     | 2014-12-10
| 2  | 1      | 5      | 2014-12-12
| 3  | 2      | 50     | 2014-12-12

Table2 :
_________________________________________________
| ID | UserID | Amount | Description  | Date     |
_________________________________________________
| 1  | 2      | 50     | Test Payment | 2014-12-10
```

I want the user to calculate the balance. And i use this MySQL code

```
SELECT
Distinct(UserID) As User,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) AS Credit,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User) AS Received,
((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User) As Balance
FROM Table1 WHERE Balance>0
```

but i can't where by as statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access [aliases in `WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). You should either put full expression there or use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT
Distinct(UserID) As User,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) AS Credit,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User) AS Received,
((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User) As Balance
FROM Table1 
HAVING Balance>0
```

-using full expression in `WHERE` is a weird thing in most cases since it will cause calculating it twice.

Comment: Or you can put everything inside a subselect, but having is the way to go here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tabel.*
FROM (
SELECT
Distinct(UserID) As User,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) AS Credit,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User) AS Received,
((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table1 WHERE UserID=User) - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Amount),0) FROM Table2 WHERE UserID=User)) as Balance
FROM Table1
)  as tabel
WHERE BALANCE > 0
```